# Autofac and contravariance : resolving to more derived type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, contravariance, marker-interfaces

Am writing a generic message handler and need to get various message handlers via AutoFac. The basic definition of the message handler is:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<in TMessage> :
    IMessageHandler
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    Task<IMessageResult> Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

I have also defined a marker interface so that these can be easily registered in AutoFac

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
}
```

A Sample message handler is:

```
public class CreatedEventHandler : IMessageHandler<CreatedEvent>
{
    public Task<IMessageResult> Handle(CreatedEvent message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And these are nicely registered named via Autofac using

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t => typeof(IMessageHandler).IsAssignableFrom(t))
       .Named<IMessageHandler>(t => t.Name.Replace("Handler", string.Empty))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This all works fine. However, when I need to resolve a handler, i have an issue

```
// handler returned is non null and of type marker interface IMessageHandler
var handler = container.Resolve("CreatedEvent");

// This is null. I just can't understand why
var createdEventHander = handler as IMessageHandler<IMessage>;
```

Why is the cast above returns null? Even though the contravariance is defined in the `IMessageHandler<>` interface.

How can I resolve the appropriate handlers?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Autofac. This is how variance works in C#/CLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops!

```
// Covariance
handler as IMessageHandler<IMessage>;
```

Your `handler` has a generic argument that isn't `IMessage` but an `IMessage` implementation. Thus, this is *covariance* (you're upcasting a generic argument).

Since I don't know your actual software architecture I can't provide you a solution. At least, you know why the whole cast results in `null`.

### Possible solution with a very little effort...

Your message handlers could both implement `IMessageHandler<ConcreteEvent>` and a new non-generic interface `IMessageHandler`:

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
      Task<IMessageResult> Handle(IMessage message);
}

public interface IMessageHandler<TMessage> : IMessageHandler
       where TMessage : IMessage
{
       Task<IMessageResult> Handle(TMessage message);
}

public class CreatedEventHandler : IMessageHandler<CreatedEvent>
{
    public Task<IMessageResult> Handle(CreatedEvent message)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // I would implement the non-generic Handle(IMessage) explicitly
    // to hide it from the public surface. You'll access it when successfully
    // casting a reference to IMessageHandler
    Task<IMessageResult> IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage message) 
    {
         return Handle((CreatedEvent)message);
    }
}
```

Now the whole cast will work because your classes will explicitly implement `IMessageHandler<IMessage>`.

And to avoid repeating yourself too much, you can implement an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MessageHandler<TMessage> : IMessageHandler<TMessage>
       where TMessage : IMessage
{
        public abstract Task<IMessageResult> Handle(TMessage message);

        // I would implement the non-generic Handle(IMessage) explicitly
        // to hide it from the public surface. You'll access it when successfully
        // casting a reference to IMessageHandler
        Task<IMessageResult> IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage message) 
        {
             return Handle((TMessage)message);
        }
}
```

Finally, your concrete message handlers would look as follows:

```
public class CreatedEventHandler : MessageHandler<CreatedEvent>
{
    public Task<IMessageResult> Handle(CreatedEvent message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That is, your cast can be turned to just `handler as IMessageHandler`.

Comment: That looks like an elegant solution. However, I get a compilation error on MessageHandler abstract class: 'MessageHandler<TMessage>' cannot implement both 'IMessageHandler<TMessage>' and 'IMessageHandler<IMessage>' because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions

Comment: @sppc42 uhm you're right. For now I've dropped that part. I'll edit my answer later with a fix ;)

Comment: @sppc42 Check my edit answer. Now I've introduced a non-generic interface to fulfill the same requirement that we couldn't implement with my previous answer text.

Comment: @sppc42 No problem, you're welcome! I'm glad it worked well in your scenario. My worries go now about if it's just a *patch* on a design flaw or it's the right solution in your scenario. This consideration is up to you now! ;)